# How to display the font name menu item appear in same font

Tags: java, html, css, gwt, gxt

I have a menu item which lists all the fonts available. For eg., I want "Times New Roman" to be displayed in Times New Roman format. Similarly, Arial should be displayed in Arial format. Below image displays everything in the default format.

[image]

Comment: you need to use js or jquery with switch statement

Comment: In that case  you have to add all font-family in your code and give class name for your list and add font-family for thatm

Answer (score 1):

For gxt you can use `MenuItem.setHTML()` and set required font-family in style. E.g.:

```
String[] fonts = {
        "Times New Roman",
        "Arial",
        "Helvetica",
        "Courier New",
        "Courier"
};

Menu fontsMenu = new Menu();
for(String font : fonts){
    MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem();
    menuItem.setHTML("<span style='font-family: "+font+"'>"+font+"</span>");
    fontsMenu.add(menuItem);
}
```